# What place should I put those source that's not defined in TFS2010

Tags: tfs

I have some source code and other artifacts such as images that are not created in Visual Studio 2010. I want to put them into TFS 2010 version control, how can I do this?

Comment: Add them to TFS..?  I'm not sure your question makes much sense.  Are you asking how to use TFS?

Comment: yes,I find it's very difficult to use TFS

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you read the documentation?  What sort of source code do you have, and what code is already in your TFS?  This question is very open ended and not very precise, which isn't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: I know how to create a project in vs2010 and add it to source control. Howerver, the question is there are some files writed by other develope language, and some pictures, and I also want to put them into version control, how could I do it? Thank you!

Comment: In Visual Studio, open Source Control explorer and click the "Add files" button...

Comment: I had try to add an image to my project by this way, but I can't view the image through the tfs web.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't view the image through the tfs web?

Comment: access the tfs through brower.I can see these code files through brower and load them, but I can't open the image.

Comment: Can you see the images through source control explorer in VS2010?  If you can (which you probably can) then the files *are* in TFS and what you're seeing is a limitation of the web client.

Comment: If I want to download the image from the tfs, how could I do it?

Comment: Use Source control explorer, or right click the link in web client and download the target, probably.

Comment: I reopened only because someone is going to try and give an *epic* answer.  If we get it, great, if not, we'll re-close it.

Comment: In addition, the TFS Power tools includes Windows explorer extensions, so you can right click and do TFS commands from the windows explorer.  It might be part of the advanced options.  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS does not care what the format of your files is;  you can use TFS to store **any** type of file - whether it was created in Visual Studio or any other program.  This is true of all TFS versions.

The comments already somewhat address how to [add a file to Source Control using Source Control Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181374.aspx#AddNonSolToVC);  Once you have a [workspace mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753.aspx), copy files or folders into a mapped folder in your workspace, right-cick on the folder you added the file to in Source Contol Explorer and select the option to *Add Items to Folder*; This will launch a wizard that you can use to let TFS know that you want to add the selected file(s) or folder(s) to source control - *it can be any file on your computer*.

After the files are added, [check-in yor changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181411%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) by right-clicking on the file in Source Control Explorer or by using the Pending Changes window (View menu -> Other Windows ->  Pending Changes).  Almost every source control operation in TFS is a *2-phase commit* that involves first letting TFS know what you want to do (like add or delete a file) and then actually committing that change with a check-in.

You can also perform these steps using [TF.exe from the command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or the Shell Integration Feature that is installed seperately with [Team Foundation Server Power Tools (TFPT)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/).  Please note that whilst you can list and view the contents of files in TFS using the Web Access user interface, you cannot check-in or check-out files using that interface.  Also, you will not be able to perform any source control changes without Visual Studio or at least a free version of it, named [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329).

The only qualities of files that matter to the behavior of TFS are if the file is a mergable file type or not and what the encoding of the file is; however, in most cases the default setings in TFS will be fine for you. Mergeable file types are files that TFS will enable merging for; Examples of mergable file types are text files;  Non-mergeable file types are file types that you would not want to merge, like pictures or Microsoft Excel files. You can read more about [Managing File Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181457.aspx) on the Microsoft site.

Comment: Q: Is TFS still as bad as MSVSS always used to be? [Source Control: Anything But Visual Source Safe](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/source-control-anything-but-sourcesafe.html)

Comment: @paulsm4 - LOL! I don't know if _anything_ will ever be that bad.  Amazing how many people still use it though! <Sigh> - In my mind, MS VSS is to TFS as MS Access is to SQL Server.  Also, TFS does more than most people (especially devs) realize (work/project/defect management, build, testing, detailed reporting)...  it's more than source control.  The team behind it has been doing a great job and I think TFS will [continue to gain more respect](http://bit.ly/LSSphS) as an enterprise ALM and source control solution.